# Numerical flow visualization in 2D for a moving boundary,

Tags: fluid-dynamics, visualization, numerical-modelling, navier-stokes

I have a rigid body that moves according to a set of governing ODEs, and I'd like to numerically visualize the vortices that are shed by this object.  How could I proceed?

I've been reading up on the Navier-Stokes equation and have a better grasp of it now, and I've watched some tutorials on implementing a 2D solver.  But, I still have some confusion:

Do I prescribe the movement of the rigid body, when trying to solve the N-S equations?

It would seem strange to do so, because the movement of the rigid body came from dynamical solutions to the governing ODEs.

Comment: This is a fluid-structure interaction problem. You probably won't solve it in a day.

Comment: You should read up on the "immersed boundary method".

Comment: There was a very similar post on this forum just a couple of weeks ago. It had a lot of information -- go find that!

Comment: The choice of visualization is something that depends on one's personal preferences. If you can point to a picture showing visualization of the kind that you have in mind then possibly somebody here can help produce something similar.

Comment: Ok, based on that picture what you want is a contour plot of the flow vorticity. Once you have a numerical solution for fluid variables as a function of spatial coordinates and time, just use any standard contour plot routine to plot the vorticity at a chosen time.

Comment: @user35764-- the thing is that this is a difficult problem. There is simply no easy solution to your problem as long as you want to stay faithful to the physics. Of course, if you don't care about being physically accurate (say, if your goal was to create something for an animation to be used in a Disney movie), then there are all sorts of techniques. But if you *do* want to be physically accurate, you need to understand the mathematical formulation of the problem (not trivial) as well as how to solve in computationally (also not trivial). That's just how it is.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Ok, I'll slow down a bit and give myself some time to learn.  Thanks for chatting again.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Ok, thanks for the suggestion